# Comparing two non-nested linear regression models

Tags: regression, anova, multiple-regression, linear-model, model-selection

I have two model fits that are not nested.

```
m1<-lm(response~x+d1)
m2<-lm(response~x+d2)
```

The categorical predictors (d1, d2) are the only thing that differs between the two models. The difference between d1 and d2 is that d1 has an extra factor level. I want to determine whether the addition of this extra level makes for a better fit.

I don't think I can use the anova/f-test route to compare model fits between m1 and m2 because the two models are not nested. Also, I don't think AIC would be appropriate because parsimony isn't in question. Both models have the same r-squared (see model statistics below). What is the most straight-forward way I can determine whether the addition of this extra level does or does not improve model fit? The only thing that comes to mind is that in the regression output, the extra factor level is reported as insignificant. Is that enough to determine that that extra factor level does not improve model fit, or are there better ways?

m1: 
r-squared - 0.74
f-statistic 49.48 on 3 and 53 53 DF, p-value: <0.0001

m2: 
r-squared - 0.74
f-statistic 75.5 on 2 and 54 DF, p-value: <0.0001

Comment: What's wrong with AIC? It's a common in-sample diagnostic used regardless of parsimony concerns. There are many ways to compare models, for instance, in forecasting you could try encompassing test

Comment: If the additional level is equivalent to splitting an existing group into two, then this does sound like nesting.

Comment: @EricMittman, can you elaborate? I'm not quite understanding what you mean by splitting an existing group into two.

Comment: If the levels of d1 are $\{A,B\}$ and the levels of d2 are $\{A,B1,B2\}$ so that whichever cases are $A$ when using d1 are the same as using d2 (none get added or subtracted) then the model with d2 is a refinement of the model with d1.